# X-Frame-Options: Deny all domains expect 3 domains in the web.config

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, web-config, x-frame-options

To avoid click jacking, I do want my web application to be loaded via iFrame. Have added the following configuration in the web.config to restrict the access from all domains except the following 3 domains.

```
<add name="X-Frame-Options" value="DENY" />
<add name="X-Frame-Options" value="ALLOW-FROM https://domain1 https://domain2 https://domain3" />
```

The above changes are not working.

Please let me know the right X-Frame-Options configuration to deny all the domains except 3 domains in the web.config. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, [support for ALLOW-FROM](https://caniuse.com/?search=allow-from) is not widespread. You should instead set the following header:

```
<add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="frame-ancestors domain1 domain2 domain3;" />
```

Setting Content-Security-Policy frame-ancestors [obsoletes X-Frame-Options](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#frame-ancestors-and-frame-options), so browsers will ignore any value set by that header.